# Related Categories Mode and search

Tags: categories, search, related

I have a single entry page with the url_title in segment_3.
I want to get all the other entries in that category, but also apply a search filter.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="academy-items"
related_categories_mode="yes"
search:audience="Customer-Support"}
{title}<br>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It looks like search doesn't work in this instance. Is there another way to get this data?

Comment: Do you want to get the related entries or all entries of one specific category? Please, improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to EE docs, it appears you can access the search parameter when using related_categories="yes". I just had my syntax wrong.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="academy-items"  
related_categories_mode="yes"
custom_fields="yes"
search:a-audience="Customer-Support"}
...
{/exp:channel_entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a conditional instead of search you could:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="academy-items"
    related_categories_mode="yes"
    custom_fields="yes"
}
    {if audience == "Customer-Support"}{title}<br>{/if}

    {!-- or the syntax might instead be: --}
    {if "{audience}" == "Customer-Support"}{title}<br>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Aha. It's a hack, but it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "audience" field type one of those that the search parameter supports? From [the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name):

> Only fields of the type “**Text Input**”, “**Textarea**”, and “**Drop-down
>   Lists**” are searched with this parameter.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I'm using a checkbox field type, but I thought that was accessible by the search parameter just like drop-down list - I swear it worked before. Looks like I need another solution.